# Signalr backplane oracle

Tags: oracle, signalr

Is it possible to setup a signalr backplane based on an oracle database?

We have 2 servers which have a signalr hub. Clients can be connected to server A **or** to server B. When we send a message through the hub on server A we also want that the users on server B get that message. We don't use azure since it's a internal company site. No sql server or redis as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently SignalR supports scale out by backplane only on , 
1. Azure Service Bus
2. Redis
3. SQL Server

see here : http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Edit : SignalR source code is hosted on Git https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
you can implement your own backplane to use Oracle DB

Answer (score 2):

Some one has written an Oracle backplane. https://github.com/sdl/SignalR-OracleMessageBus